# Como quebrar um loop infinito usando Ctrl-C no Java

Tags: java

Possuo um servidor multithread que fica em um loop infinito esperando por novas conexões e quero poder parar esse loop quando eu pressionar Ctrl-C (ou algo similar). Tentei utilizar [essa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32934085/6039697) solução e tentei fazer algo assim:

```
private void waitForConnections() {
    boolean done = false;
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();
            System.err.println("Exiting");
            done = true;
        }
    });

    while (!done) {
        try {
            Socket userSocket = this.serverSocket.accept();
            // Faz alguma coisa...
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Mas eu não posso alterar o valor da variável done done dentro da thread. Como posso resolver este problema da maneira mais simples e elegante possível?

Comment: Há um erro, pois o seu código nunca vai testar o ```!done```, pois tem um ```while(true)```.

Comment: O problema foi resolvido?

Comment: A pergunta é muito interessante, queria responder mas não sei se vou arrumar tempo. A propósito, acredito que esse `super.run()` não é necessário.

Comment: Sveen, Ainda não. O erro que o lemoce disse para corrigir foi um erro de digitação de código. O problema principal persiste!

Comment: Tenta setar ```setSoTimeout()```, ai o accept soltará um ```SocketTimeoutException```, para que o accept não fique em blocked infinitamente. Se isso for a solução, é porque o accept fica bloqueando a thread infinitamente, logo quando você emite o Ctrl-C, o seu código não volta para o inicio do loop e assim teste o ```!done```.

Comment: Não parece uma boa solução pois o server ficará ligado por horas e pode acontecer de nenhum cliente querer se conectar. Na sua solução o server pararia de receber solicitações depois de ocorrer o timeout.

Comment: @MichaelPacheco pode ser. Eu dei uma solução, mas o importante é o porque acontece o problema.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui uma solução temporária enquanto outras não aparecem. O que eu fiz foi apenas substituir o `ShutdownHook` por uma `Thread` normal e dentro do método `run` eu fiz um loop infinito que lê a entrada do usuário e pára quando o mesmo entra com fim de arquivo (Ctrl+D no MAC). Mas ainda não estou satisfeito com essa solução... me parece gambiarra.

Eis o meu código:

```
private void waitForConnections() {
    new Thread(this).start();

    try {
        //noinspection InfiniteLoopStatement
        while (true) {
            Socket userSocket = this.serverSocket.accept();
            allocateClient(userSocket);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // The user socket was closed by the shutdown method, so, no need for printing the stack trace.
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (s.hasNext())
        s.nextLine();

    shutdown();
}
```

O método shutdown fecha o `ServerSocket` gerando uma `IOException` dentro do loop.

Answer (score -1):

Fiz um [exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) mínimo e funcional do site do StackOverflow. No meu exemplo, não precisei adicionar um hook de finalização. O funcionamento é bem simples, foi criada uma Thread para ser o Listener da aplicação e outra Handler para tratar os clientes. Não sei se é a solução ideal para o teu problema e com certeza deve ter problemas.

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.ServerSocket;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Teste {

    static class Listener extends Thread {

        public void run() {
            try (ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(10113)){
                System.out.println("Iniciei servidor");
                while(true) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Esperando cliente");
                        Handler handler = new Handler(ss.accept());
                        handler.start();
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(-1);
            }

        }

    };

    static class Handler extends Thread {

        Socket client;

        public Handler(Socket client) {
            this.client = client;
        }

        public void run() {
            try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true)) {
                writer.println("meu super teste");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (client != null) {
                    try {
                        client.close();
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Teste.Listener listener = new Teste.Listener();
        listener.setDaemon(true);
        listener.start();
        try {
            System.out.println("esperando servidor iniciar");
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(30);
        } catch (Exception ex) {}
    }

}
```

Comment: Este código não apresenta nada relacionado ao meu problema. Eu preciso de uma maneira simples e elegante de parar o servidor quando eu quiser e desconectar todos os usuários. Mas obrigado por tentar ajudar!

Comment: Por que me negativaram?

Comment: @MichaelPacheco eu só quis mostrar que pode-se fazer Ctrl-C sem hooks ou shutdown explicito.